# Excel VBA Macros Scheduling

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office

I would like to automatically start my macro @ 9:30Am and then to schedule it to run at every 15min and end running at 3:15pm. For example - Micro should first run @ 9:30am then at 9:45, 10:00, 10:15 & so on till 3:15pm. Can anyone help me with it?

```vb
Application.OnTime "09:15:00" + TimeValue("00:15:00"), "test", "15:15:00"
```

Comment: What happened when you tried that?  What specific problem are you having?

Comment: VBA not working showing debug

Answer (score 0):

In Excel you could use the [Application.OnTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.ontime) method which schedules a procedure to be run at a specified time in the future (either at a specific time of day or after a specific amount of time has passed). For example, to run it for the first time at 9 AM you could use the following code:

```
Application.OnTime TimeValue("9:30:00"), "my_Procedure"
```

In your procedure you could schedule next iteration will schedule next run in 15 mins:

```
Sub my_Procedure()

  ' your code here which runs every 15 mins

  Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:15"), "my_Procedure"
End Sub
```